# Blazor WebAssembly and HTTP-requests. How to protect against unplanned requests?

Tags: api, httprequest, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Good afternoon!
I apologize in advance for a possibly stupid question.

I recently asked a question about connecting Blazor WebAssembly to a database. They explained to me that it was necessary to use the API and left me a link to lessons from Microsoft. Here it is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

I started doing a lesson and to test the functionality of the API, it was necessary to send requests. And at this point I have matured questions:

1. I could send requests creating new positions without any account verification. It turns out, in general, everyone can safely send such requests to the site, creating new products?
2. How to protect yourself from the above?

Comment: Read Chapter 4: Securing your API

Comment: Do I need to secure only API or the app too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) Yes everyone could access to your api if your controller doesn't have any authorization query.

2.) Out of the Box -> use [Authorize] Attribute or anything like if(user.permission == "Foo")

Check out for detail information:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-3.1
- https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-authentication-with-clientside-blazor-using-webapi-aspnet-core-identity/